# What is the meaning of the noun "remove" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a dialogue in [The Browning Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Browning_Version_(play)), a play by Terence Rattigan, which was:

> No, sir, I'm still in the lower fifth. I can't specialise until next term — that's to say, if I've got my **remove** all right.

According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/remove), *remove* means 'a form or division in some British schools', but that doesn't fit here. Shouldn't there be *result* instead of *remove*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the contrary, *remove* as a division in school does fit here and is the intended meaning.

If, at the end of the lower fifth, the student gets his remove (i.e. passes his end of year exams), then he is removed from the lower fifth and enters the upper fifth.

In British secondary education at that time, each *form* (that is - year) was numbered from first to fifth.  The fifth form took two years to complete, thus upper and lower fifth.
Later, an additional year was required as the school leaving age was increased. In my day, I attended lower then upper sixth.

On entering these higher years, students were allowed to drop the study of certain subjects and concentrate on others.  Hence the reference to specialisation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a phrasing "to get one's remove" meaning to pass or to promote a grade or exam. I can't specialise ... unless I promote.

Answer (score 0):

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remove_(education)#:%7E:text=A%20Remove%20class%20in%20education,middle%206th%20(year%2012)) discusses the notion of a "Remove Class" - unique to so-called 'public schools' (which if you are not British, you may not appreciate are in reality private or sometimes-called 'independent' schools).

Individual public schools greatly vary as to where a "remove class" fits in their system - as the Wiki article will show.

**However, in answer to the question, at those points in the education cycle where it becomes necessary to pass an exam to move on to a higher grade, success at doing so was spoken of as 'obtaining one's remove'.**

In British education moving up the grades or "forms" as we call them in Britain, is mostly based on age. (I believe it is more common in America for  pupils to have to pass tests to move themselves along).

One age group where examinations are critical to one's progress is nowadays at age 16, when you take your GCSEs. This used to be known as Year 5 (modern year 11), and to enter the "sixth form"(modern years 12 and 13) you had (and still have) to demonstrate capability. Hence the year 5 class was in times past, in certain types of school, sometimes known as "the Remove". But as the Wiki article makes clear some schools had/have a Remove class at a different age.

I mostly use the past tense as the terms "remove" and "The Remove class" are completely foreign to modern State School education, and I suspect largely obsolete in the Independent sector too.

**But in pre-WW2 jargon, among the class of people whose children attended fee-paying schools, 'to obtain one's remove'meant simply to pass the necessary tests to move on to a higher level.**

As stated the terms have little relevance to modern education.

The idea of 'The Remove' as a school class, as the Wiki article indicates, was immortalised in the schoolboy novels by Frank Richards about the character *Billy Bunter* otherwise known as *The Owl of the Remove*.

**Health warning**: While they may be good social history, Frank Richards' writings, which make fun of an overweight child, and include incipient racism, which mildly ridiculed the character Hurree Jamsett Ram Sing (the son of an Indian Maharaja) would not pass any test of political correctness in today's world.